# Change Time Format

Tags: 7, datetime

I'm confused about all of the time formats and then each format seems to have a matching format with a `pm` attached at the end. Does the `pm` signify that it will use 12 hour am and 12 hour pm vs 24 hour time? Pic attached:

[image]

Comment: In a word, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You happened to look at the example time formats at the wrong time of day.  If it was an hour later, say 1:04 pm you would have seen

- 26.08.2012 - 13:04
- 08/26/2012 - 1:04pm (highlighted)

By the way you can also define your own formats to be used with the "Long", "Medium" and "Short" date types, if you don't like the pre-canned options. Look for the "Formats" tab under the date time settings:

`admin/config/regional/date-time` in Drupal 7 (the screen shot is D7.x)

Further, you can also define new date types (e.g. I often create "Time of day" or "Year") that you can then assign a particular format (ideally one that only shows hh:mm:ss AM/PM  -`h:i:s A`- or year - `Y` - to match your naming convention).  It is a bit confusing, but it is a two step process, but it is very flexible.  Creating a "Year" only date type is great for using with the [Views module](http://drupal.org/project/views) to make display groupings on year.